# Is it possible to make an APK file with sharedPreferences data from install App in device?

Tags: android, apk

This is first time I put an input in my app, The input saved in shared Preferences.

I want to share my app with other persons including **shared preferences data**.

How can I build an `APK` file with shared preferences saved data from the installed app from device?

Please help me out

Comment: Not possible. But you can save the data in shared preference when user opens the app for the first time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025234/how-can-i-share-a-sharedpreferences-file-across-two-different-android-apps