# share data between two flavoured apps having same package name using shared preferences

Tags: android

I have one app which is using different build variant(flavor), Now I want to share data between these flavored apps(different apps for End User). Now my question is that how can I use shared preferences to share some data amongst the flavored apps as only one package name mentioned in the manifest file and that one package is valid for all the flavored apps. I have tried the below approach and failed to share data.

//To set data

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MyPref, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("UserEmail", m_email);
editor.putString("UserPass", m_pass);
editor.putString("LoggedUserName", m_statusData);
editor.commit();
```

//To Get data

```
Context con = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext("my_packagename", 0);
SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(MyPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
EmailId = pref.getString("UserEmail", email);//got always null
Password = pref.getString("UserPass", Password);//got always null
```

But it is not working. What to do now?

Comment: where is your `MyPref`

Comment: private final String MyPref="Setting"; // a constant

Comment: did you add `android:sharedUserId`? both app's manifest file.

Comment: try to Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY instead of MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated in API level 17

Comment: I have already tried Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY instead of MODE_WORLD_READABLE but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment so i post it as an answer...

I guess this is what you are looking for:

[How can I share a SharedPreferences file across two different android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025234/how-can-i-share-a-sharedpreferences-file-across-two-different-android-apps)

you need to use `android:sharedUserId` in your Manifest.

Comment: I am using android:sharedUserId

Answer (score 0):

While reading Word readable data shared by first app, we should create shared pref object like-

Replacing

```
getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

in the second app to get updated value in the second app.

Comment: @alam did you try CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY and `android:sharedUserId` in manifest