# Access data from other application saved in preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

If an application has saved data using SharedPreference like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = getDefaultSharedPreferences.edit();
preferencesEditor.putInt("count", mValue);
preferencesEditor.apply();
```

can an other application have access to these data after reboot like this for example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getDefaultSharedPreferences();
int value = sharedPref.getInt("count",0);
```

And if it is not posssible, how is possible from an application to store variable so that other application have access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but both apps need to be signed by the same certificates among other things, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748043/3836923) for details.

An application can also share and access data from a public [content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and this is usually the recommended way of sharing data among different applications.

You can also have a shared file in storage that both apps can read and write.